# Cross domain request to localhost from a BHO injected JavaScript (in IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, bho

I have a working prototype of a BHO (simple C# with COM interop) which injects JavaScript to any page which is loaded by IE. Simple scripts are working like console.log(..) etc.

My goal is to make AJAX requests from the injected javascript to localhost. I understand it's an X domain request, but can't figure out how to implement it.

I carefully read about XMLHttpRequest and XDomainRequest (both gives me Access Denied)
Btw I would like to send/receive JSON and XDomainRequest allows only plain/text (why?, surely not security issue enabling plain/text but not allowing json...) Also I've read XDomainRequest does not allow localhost.

I understand that response header should allow X domain with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' (Is this the response of the page I am injecting into?)

Maybe I can modify/patch the response header to allow X domain from my BHO? Is this possible?

As a last resort I considered make the request in my C# BHO. However this means to call from javascript to C# (maybe it's working) but the main problem that this call is a synchronous call. Even if I issue the request in async way in C# in it completion handler then I must call back a javascript completion handler. This sounds as terrible overenginering  calling from javascript to C# then calling back from C# to javascript not talking about the robustness and perfomance loss.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you please explain how to inject JavaScript to any page which is loaded by IE?